# How I can get id selector connected with item id

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, list, css-selectors

I have list of buttons on my app list with items, which I can like. I am using here `id` selector. I would like to use id selector with id of item - to make id selector unique.

How I can get id of item and connect them to id selector for this result?
1. #voteup-2
2. #voteup-section-2

I was trying use `data-id`

Here is my jquery part:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(event){
                $(document).on('click', '#voteup', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var pk = $(this).attr('value');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "{% url 'qa:answer_voteup' %}",
                        data: {'id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response){
                            $('#voteup-section').html(response['form'])
                            console.log($('#voteup-section').html(response['form']))
                        },
                        error: function(rs, e){
                            console.log(rs.responseText);
                        },
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Button in html part, here I have id selector with `voteup-section-{{ answer.id }}`

```
<div id="voteup-section-{{ answer.id }}" data-id="{{ answer.id }}">
    <form action="{% url 'qa:answer_voteup' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" id="voteup-{{ answer.id }}" name="answer_id" value="{{ answer.id }}" {% if is_voted_up %} class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Voted up! {% else %} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Vote up!{% endif %} <span class="badge badge-light">{{ answer.total_vote_up }}</span></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is on the client-side, why not to show the client-side code?

Comment: *I would like to use id selector with id of item - to make id selector unique.* That's exactly how you do use `id` based selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just mean that you want your click handler to work for all these elements?:

```
<button type="submit" id="voteup-{{ answer.id }}"...
```

You can use the [starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to capture all buttons where the `id` starts with a known value.  Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[id^="voteup-"]', function(event){
    //...
});
```

This would handle the click for all `<button>` elements in the document where their `id` starts with `"voteup-"`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to assign a class to the buttons.

```
<button ... class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-vote" ...>Vote up!</button>
```

I've simplified the button HTML to just the class to illustrate the point. The class "btn-vote" can be anything of your choosing. The jQuery selector then becomes

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn-vote', function(event){
    //...
}
```